# Keep npm library up-to-date

Tags: npm, webhooks

In my project I have an external npm library.  That Library is an icon library. Each time I have a new icon to insert, I need to `npm publish` then run `npm update my-icon-library` in my project.

Is there a way to keep my project updated **automatically** each time the icon library is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the icons library inside **package.json** with a proper version range.

It'll not be done automatically , you just have to issue npm install inside your project in order to update that library.

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "latest"
}
```

Checkout npm [Ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#ranges).

Comment: So there is no way to `automatically`  have the latest library?

Comment: @IsraGab yes you can by having “latest” as the version

Comment: That was my question, can you please update your answer and giving example so I can accept your answer :)